# pinchzoom in hammer.js notworking

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

I am trying to get pinchzoom effect using hammer.js when download it. It is not working could any one say what is the mistake in the code.

Visit `[<http://jsfiddle.net/wNfc9/10/>][1]`

Comment: What devices are you testing in/targeting?

Comment: androind and ios both

Comment: Tested on iOS and it worked (the pinch/zoom). What specifically is not working for you? One thing I recommend is testing with the shell: http://fiddle.jshell.net/wNfc9/10/show/light/

Comment: Hey Jack this is working. Now what happens when i add tap event on which a popup is to be opened, pinch and tap event are not working simultaneously. working example : http://jsfiddle.net/wZX79/